# use python to split a video file into a set of parts

Tags: python, ffmpeg, vlc, mplayer, pyffmpeg

I use the following python code to split a FLV video file into a set of parts ,when finished ,only the first part video can be played ,the other parts are corrupted.I wonder why and Is there some correct ways to split video files

the code format is mussy here
please see the formated code [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.lang.python/lldCzWOrj8s)

Comment: Did you do any research on the .flv format before you started? Obviously, you can't just grab some bytes from the middle of the file and expect them to make up a playable video. (And why did you tag with 3 tools that are completely unrelated and a Python library you didn't use?)

Comment: If your intention is to split a large file for backup onto smaller media, the file will be okay once you join the parts back together. If you want to create smaller files, which can be played independently, you can't split it this way with FLV files. Google for `split flv` to find a program to split FLV files.

Answer (score 0):

Data formats consist normally of "two" (multiple) things. A container and a codec. One handles the way a data is aligned and put together, while the second handles the payload and its compression or representation only.

What you did was basically to just cut the data into separate chunks without really understanding how the data is aligned, formatted and encoded (as the others have commented).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:FLVPacket.png

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video